# Using ForeignKey('Page') inside Relationship Model

Tags: wagtail

I have created Relationshim Model to use inside `InlinePanel` so if I click chose a page i get nothing

[image]

Here is my models.py:

```
class GroupstageTournamentModel(ClusterableModel):
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default="", verbose_name="Match №:")
    starts_at = models.DateTimeField(default="",)
    # Team 1
    team_1 = models.ForeignKey(
        TeamRooster,
        null=True, default="", verbose_name='Erste Team',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    team_1_dress = ColorField(default='#ff0000', blank=True, verbose_name='Dress')
    team_1_first_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat 1. HZ')
    team_1_first_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte 1. HZ')
    team_1_second_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat 2. HZ')
    team_1_second_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte 2. HZ')
    team_1_shootout_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat Shootout')
    team_1_shootout_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Schootout Punkte')
    team_1_total_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat Total')
    team_1_total_points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte Total')
    # Team 2
    team_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        TeamRooster,
        null=True, default="", verbose_name='Zweite Team',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    team_2_dress = ColorField(default='#ff0000', blank=True, verbose_name='Dress')
    team_2_first_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat 1. HZ')
    team_2_first_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte 1. HZ')
    team_2_second_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat 2. HZ')
    team_2_second_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte 2. HZ')
    team_2_shootout_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat Shootout')
    team_2_shootout_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Schootout Punkte')
    team_2_total_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat Total')
    team_2_total_points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte Total')

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('number', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('starts_at', classname="col6"),
        # Team 1
        FieldPanel('team_1', classname="col9"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_dress', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_first_halftime_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_second_halftime_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_shootout_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_total_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_first_halftime_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_second_halftime_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_shootout_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_total_points', classname="col3"),
        # Team 2
        FieldPanel('team_2', classname="col9"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_dress', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_first_halftime_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_second_halftime_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_shootout_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_total_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_first_halftime_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_second_halftime_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_shootout_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_total_points', classname="col3"),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} vs {} {} - {}'.format(self.team_1, self.team_2, self.starts_at, self.number)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Gruppenphase Spiel'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Gruppenphase'

class GroupstageScreencastRelationship(Orderable, models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey('ScreencastPage',
        related_name='groupstage_screencast_relationship')
    match = models.ForeignKey('GroupstageTournamentModel',
        related_name='match_screen_relationship')
    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('match')
    ]


class ScreencastPage(Page):
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel(
            'groupstage_screencast_relationship', label="Playing First",
            panels=None, max_num=1),
    ]

    parent_page_types = ['home.HomePage']
```

If i click on choose a page in console traceback I see following:

```
Not Found: /admin/choose-page/
[12/Feb/2018 15:09:03] "GET /admin/choose-page/?page_type=tournament.groupstagetournamentmodel HTTP/1.1" 404 4621
Not Found: /admin/choose-page/
[12/Feb/2018 15:09:04] "GET /admin/choose-page/?page_type=tournament.groupstagetournamentmodel HTTP/1.1" 404 4621
Not Found: /admin/choose-page/
[12/Feb/2018 15:09:05] "GET /admin/choose-page/?page_type=tournament.groupstagetournamentmodel HTTP/1.1" 404 4621
Not Found: /admin/choose-page/
[12/Feb/2018 15:09:05] "GET /admin/choose-page/?page_type=tournament.groupstagetournamentmodel HTTP/1.1" 404 4621
```

I also created `GroupstageTournamentModel(ClusterableModel)` models first.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is failing because `GroupstageTournamentModel` does not inherit from Page -
 `PageChooserPanel` does not work on non-page models. You could either register `GroupstageTournamentModel` as a snippet (http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/topics/snippets.html) and use `SnippetChooserPanel`, or just use a plain FieldPanel (which will give you a plain dropdown list).

Comment: Yes, as well as in backerydemo you used it to chose autors, but i want to use pagechooser becoz it has a search function, so if i add 1000 matches it will be very hard to handl that without search.